# How to implement onClick in custom preference that starts new activity?

Tags: android

How to make onClick in custom preference start new acitivity (startActivityForResult)?

I would like my custom preference to start new activity and when it returns result it should save it in the preferences. I know how to implement saving but I am not sure how to implement onClick.

This is what I did in custom Preference class:

```
@Override
protected void onClick() {
    Intent pickLocationIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
    pickLocationIntent.putExtra("latitude", 0.0);
    pickLocationIntent.putExtra("longitude", 0.0);
    startActivityForResult(pickLocationIntent, REQUEST_LOCATION);
}
```

It does not allow me to use startActivityForResult like this.

**Edit**

To summarise: how would one implement custom preference which when clicked opens new activity?

**Edit2**

Here's the solution if anyone needs it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24885463/9801221

Answer (score 0):

Put this `android:onClick="anyname"` inside your layout item for which you want a click listener.

`public void anyname(View v) {
    Intent pickLocationIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
    pickLocationIntent.putExtra("latitude", 0.0);
    pickLocationIntent.putExtra("longitude", 0.0);
    startActivityForResult(pickLocationIntent, REQUEST_LOCATION);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

To implement a onClick event your class e.g. your MainActivity has to implement the OnClickListener interface from the package View, e.g. `public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {` . Then you need something to click on thats a view and you implement the OnClickListener by writing:`View.setOnClickListener(this)` in your MainActivity. Whenever the user touches this view the onClick method of the MainActivity will be called.

To get a result from the MapsActivity you just implement `onActivityResult()` method in your Activity.

I hope i didn't understood you wrong. :)